# Matrix of $\phi$-stable operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space and $\phi:V\rightarrow V$ an endomorphism. We say that $W$ is $\phi$-stable if $\phi(W)\subseteq W$.

During my geometry class, my teacher told us that if a subspace $W$ is $\phi$-stable, then $\phi$ can be represented by a block matrix of the kind 
$$\alpha(\phi)=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
B' & C'\\
0 & D'\\
\end{array} 
\right)
$$ without further justification. I suppose the matrix would have that form in a basis $B_v=(w_1,\dots,w_k,v_{k+1},\dots v_n)$, where $(w_1,\dots,w_k)$ is a basis of $W$. Intuitively, I can guess that this has to do with the fact that the image of $W$ cannot contain any vector that lies in $\langle v_{k+1},\dots,v_n \rangle$, but I cannot really understand why the $0$ block is in that position.

Can somebody point a way of explaining this fact?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$ and let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$, where $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is a basis of $W$ and $\{v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $W^\perp$.

Let $\phi : V \to V$ be linear and be given the matrix representation with respect to the given basis.

Column $j$ of $\alpha(\phi)$ is $\begin{bmatrix} a_{1j} \\ a_{2j} \\ \vdots \\ a_{nj} \end{bmatrix}$ where $\phi(v_j) = \alpha_{1j} v_1 + \alpha_{2j} v_2 + \cdots + \alpha_{nj} v_n$.

If $j \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$ then $\phi(v_j) \in \mathrm{Span} \{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ so that $\alpha_{(k+1)j} = \cdots = \alpha_{nj} = 0$. This is the source of the $0$'s in the lower left corner: if $1 \le j \le k$ and $(k+1) \le i \le n$ then $a_{ij} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear. I will accept your answer tomorrow, to not discourage other users who wish to post other interesting answers to my question.